# Timed out script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the following code in order to avoid using an IMPORTRANGE() formula. The data I'm getting is over 50k rows so that's why I'm using App Script.

But now I'm getting the following error:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id

```js
function Live_Data_importing() {

var raw_live = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("someURL").getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var selected_columns = raw_live.getRange("A:Q").getValues().map(([a,,,,e,f,g,,i,j,,l,,n,o,]) => [a,e,f,g,i,j,l,n,o] ); 

var FF_filtered = selected_columns.filter(row=>row[8]=="somedata");

var FF_Hourly_live_data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("somesheet");

FF_Hourly_live_data.getRange(2, 1, FF_filtered.length, FF_filtered[0].length).setValues(FF_filtered);
}
```

How can I fix this error? I also made a copy of the file but script is still running the same error.

Comment: Also ranges like this `getRange("A:Q").` will generate many nulls between getLastRow() and getMaxRows() try using `"A1:Q" + Sheet.getLastRow()`

Comment: Perhaps the id/url is incorrect.  Atleast that's what the error message suggests to me

Comment: The ID is not incorrect because I'm getting about 2k rows of data and that's when the error pops up. But in reality there are over 40k rows of data

Comment: I'm basically trying to get all those columns based on a criteria on one column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244410/discussion-between-mau-and-cooper).

Comment: Apparently your spreadsheet is too heavy for the Spreadsheet Service (SpreadsheetApp). Try using the Advanced Spreadsheet Service or the Sheets API

Comment: Maybe, consider getting the data in two runs (first one half of the data, then the second one)?

Comment: you might want to look into BigQuery and the Sheets BigQuery API

Comment: How can I use thge advanced spreadsheet service or the sheets API to acomplish my request??? Could you guys kindly help me?

Answer (score 0):

#### Tested this on smaller set of data

It works okay

```
function Live_Data_importing() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var raw_live = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var selected_columns = raw_live.getRange("A1:Q" + raw_live.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([a, , , , e, f, g, , i, j, , l, , n, o,]) => [a, e, f, g, i, j, l, n, o]);//fix this range
  var FF_filtered = selected_columns.filter(row => row[8] == 0);//My data is all integers
  var FF_Hourly_live_data = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");//output sheet
  FF_Hourly_live_data.getRange(2, 1, FF_filtered.length, FF_filtered[0].length).setValues(FF_filtered);
}
```

Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 | COL17 | COL18 | COL19 | COL20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 18 | 13 | 0 | 7 | 5 | 11 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 17 | 0 | 8 | 11 | 18 | 0 | 16 | 1 | 8 |
| 0 | 16 | 16 | 9 | 5 | 0 | 16 | 8 | 14 | 0 | 7 | 4 | 3 | 15 | 8 | 19 | 18 | 4 | 18 | 10 |
| 9 | 14 | 7 | 16 | 17 | 13 | 17 | 4 | 8 | 6 | 19 | 18 | 9 | 18 | 12 | 1 | 8 | 19 | 12 | 10 |
| 13 | 17 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 3 | 7 | 16 | 14 | 13 | 1 | 5 | 16 | 12 | 2 | 3 | 14 | 3 | 0 | 9 |
| 4 | 17 | 14 | 5 | 9 | 13 | 18 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 14 | 1 | 12 | 7 | 10 | 1 | 15 | 4 | 14 | 5 |
| 1 | 17 | 13 | 17 | 3 | 1 | 17 | 8 | 19 | 7 | 14 | 18 | 2 | 17 | 1 | 16 | 2 | 19 | 13 | 15 |
| 7 | 4 | 9 | 0 | 11 | 14 | 11 | 7 | 12 | 14 | 3 | 19 | 14 | 13 | 18 | 12 | 16 | 19 | 19 | 6 |
| 7 | 6 | 10 | 5 | 15 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 2 | 16 | 4 | 14 | 18 | 14 | 2 | 16 | 16 | 5 | 15 | 16 |
| 4 | 5 | 9 | 6 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 15 | 14 | 8 | 19 | 8 | 4 | 10 | 12 | 12 | 4 | 6 | 10 | 12 |
| 11 | 15 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 17 | 19 | 10 | 4 | 11 | 2 | 10 | 16 | 12 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 11 | 0 | 14 | 8 | 13 | 13 | 4 | 2 | 16 | 18 | 10 | 14 | 5 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 5 | 15 |
| 0 | 6 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 18 | 1 | 1 | 11 | 13 | 7 | 13 | 5 | 15 | 5 | 13 | 17 | 18 | 14 | 19 |
| 0 | 17 | 10 | 6 | 10 | 16 | 16 | 0 | 18 | 19 | 12 | 8 | 15 | 1 | 11 | 4 | 19 | 4 | 17 | 14 |
| 4 | 14 | 14 | 6 | 16 | 8 | 15 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 14 | 14 | 16 | 9 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 4 |
| 8 | 3 | 8 | 5 | 12 | 15 | 5 | 19 | 14 | 0 | 1 | 6 | 12 | 2 | 19 | 10 | 10 | 19 | 13 | 19 |
| 0 | 5 | 14 | 7 | 2 | 17 | 3 | 10 | 2 | 14 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 18 | 5 | 1 | 13 | 13 | 3 | 13 |
| 10 | 18 | 18 | 4 | 18 | 11 | 0 | 7 | 13 | 9 | 18 | 13 | 9 | 2 | 0 | 16 | 15 | 3 | 9 | 14 |
| 12 | 15 | 15 | 7 | 16 | 13 | 14 | 1 | 4 | 12 | 18 | 9 | 6 | 14 | 18 | 11 | 16 | 2 | 18 | 15 |
| 15 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 16 | 5 | 18 | 2 | 6 | 14 | 18 | 11 | 1 | 9 | 15 | 13 | 8 | 8 | 19 |
| 11 | 19 | 14 | 0 | 7 | 15 | 1 | 10 | 8 | 9 | 14 | 14 | 15 | 3 | 11 | 13 | 4 | 10 | 5 | 16 |

Comment: So how can I fix my error?

Comment: It could be in your data.  I'd start with fixing the range and then use the debugger to go through subsets of your data.

Comment: You might also try adding try catch to see what the data looks like when you start getting errors